# Passing .NET variable value in to Java Script variable

Tags: javascript, .net

I have an HTML page which is then taken by some .NET code at the back end and displayed as on out put Page.

In the HTML page I can display values of some variables like

```
<PrintingField:PrintingQuantity>

<PrintingField:ClientPrintingNotes>
```

I want to capture the values of one of the variable in to java script variable in the same HTML page. For example:

```
Var T1 = <PrintingField:ClientPrintingNotes>
```

So that I can validate T1 with some java script functions.

please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax: `<PrintingField:PrintingQuantity>`  Are you using some kind of template engine?  Normally ASP .NET values are emitted to the page in classic syntax (`<% =SomeValue %>`) or in more recent MVC Razor syntax (`@Model.SomeValue`).  Either of these would work fine within JavaScript code (though the latter often requires some creative use of the `<text>` tag to get the parser to work).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a literal control on the aspx page and jquery to retrieve the value.

On the aspx you have this markup:

```
<div id="TheDivID"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="SomeValue" /></div>
```

In the code behind C# code, you then write:

```
SomeValue.Text = MyVar.ToString();
```

And then in javascript you have:

```
var TheValueFromServer = $('#TheID').text();
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Why not just use a hidden form field for the same effect and use `.val()` instead of `.text()` to get the value from it?  It seems like a hidden field is more apt for holding a value than some random `div` display element on the page (which then would need to be styled as hidden).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `PrintingField`, but I assume it's a custom class you have. If you're just accessing a property of that class you can accomplish this by using:

```
var T1 = '<%= PrintingField.ClientPrintingNotes %>';
```

If it's an instance class, `PrintingField` will have to be the name of the variable. Keep in mind this is not a 2-way recognition. This happens when the page is built and pushed out to the client.

Comment: @Krishnam: That would suggest that whatever you're passing in does not have a translated value.

Comment: Notice the difference between `PrintingField.ClientPrintingNotes` and `PrintingField:ClientPrintingNotes`.  I'm not really sure _what_ the OP is passing in, but it's not a standard .NET value.  @Krishnam: What exactly is this syntax you're using?

Answer (score 0):

To access properties defined in code-behind inside your HTML part, you would need to define your proprties or variables as public, and then use them as follows:

```
<%= this.MyVariable %>
```

Hope this helps,
Regards